# Why would one use %8.8 over %08 in a printf format string?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Just came across some (very) legacy code (originally written as C but now compiled as C++ too)  and a use of the width specifier to zero pad a string

```c
void main()
{
    unsigned long val = 2413;
    printf("V1: %08lu \n", val);
    printf("V2: %8.8lu \n", val);
}
```

The results are identical

```
V1: 00002413
V2: 00002413
```

So why would one use V2? Was it some legacy aspect of the std lib from the days of yore?

Compiler details : Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25019 for x86

Comment: With strings, there's a difference between `%8s` and `%8.8s` — the latter truncates if the string is longer than 8.  There's another difference; `0` is not a valid modifier for `%s`.  The `%8.8lu` doesn't seem to buy you much compared with `%.8lu`; there's not much difference between `%.8lu` and `%08lu`, though `0` is older and the `.` was added to C90 (so that's pretty old these days).

Comment: They're just two different ways of achieving the same thing. The first tends to be preferred because the padding character is stated explicitly.

Comment: `printf` is a function of the C standard library. The question is not about C++.

Comment: Your code can't be standard C++; C++ requires that the return value of `main()` is an `int`.  C allows implementations to let you use alternative return types; the Microsoft C implementation allows you to use `void`.  Their C++ may also allow it, but it is in contravention of the standard which does not.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the details.

Comment: If you want to keep twice language tags, for me your question is too broad, you need to understand that `printf()` has different standard in C and C++ in 2017. Like `printf()` is idiomatic C, I will advise you to choice C. You could create two question if you want C++ too.

Comment: Note that this question is the subject of a MSO question — [User goes into edit war for C tag removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350785/user-goes-into-edit-war-for-c-tag-removal/).  Please be cautious about editing the question or its tags.

Answer (score 17):

For *unsigned* integer types there's no difference. For negative values of *signed* integer types you will see different output

```
long val = -2413;
printf("V1: %08ld\n", val);
printf("V2: %8.8ld\n", val);

V1: -0002413
V2: -00002413
```

The `.8` part of `%8.8ld` specifies *the minimum number of digits to appear*. And the `-` sign is not considered a digit. For this reason, the second version is required to always print 8 digits. If the value is negative, the `-` sign will have no choice but to become the 9th character printed, thus violating the requested field width of 8.

The `%08ld` version has no requirement to print at least 8 digits, which is why the `-` sign occupies one character *inside* the field width of 8 and only 7 digits are printed.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc9022cc0ef3e097

Comment: Hmm are you sure?

Comment: @gsamaras: Yes. `.8` part specifies *the minimum number of digits to appear*. Which means that you will always see 8 digits. The `-` does not count. This allows it to break out of 8 character field witdth. In the first version there's no "minimum" requirement, which is why `-` eats aways one space and results in less digits being output.

Comment: AnT great, just checked and you right. Yes I know about that ( see my answer =) ), I was just wasn't sure. +1.

Comment: "For unsigned integer types there's no difference."  --> `"#"` flag will impart a difference with unsigned values.  `"%#08lx"` vs `"%#8.8lx"`

Answer (score 7):

As I noted in a comment, with strings, there's a difference between `%8s` and `%8.8s` — the latter truncates if the string is longer than `8`. There's another difference; `0` is not a valid modifier for `%s`. The `%8.8lu` isn't really different from `%.8lu`; there's not much difference between `%.8lu` and `%08lu`, though `0` is older and the `.` was added to C90 (so that's pretty old these days).  There's a difference between `%.8ld` and `%08ld`, though, when the values are negative.

Here's some code that illustrates some of the vagaries of the integer formats for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) — for both signed and unsigned values.  Note that if you have `%8.6lu` rather than `%8.8lu` (similarly for signed), you get interesting differences.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void test_ul(void)
{
    char *fmt[] =
    {
        "%08lu",
        "%8.8lu",
        "%.8lu",
        "%8.6lu",
        "%6.8lu",
    };
    enum { NUM_FMT = sizeof(fmt) / sizeof(fmt[0]) };
    unsigned long val[] = { 2413LU, 234512349LU };
    enum { NUM_VAL = sizeof(val) / sizeof(val[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FMT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_VAL; j++)
        {
            printf("%8s: [", fmt[i]);
            printf(fmt[i], val[j]);
            puts("]");
        }
    }
}

static void test_sl(void)
{
    char *fmt[] =
    {
        "%08ld",
        "%8.8ld",
        "%.8ld",
        "%8.6ld",
        "%6.8ld",
    };
    enum { NUM_FMT = sizeof(fmt) / sizeof(fmt[0]) };
    long val[] = { +2413L, -2413L, +234512349L, -234512349L };
    enum { NUM_VAL = sizeof(val) / sizeof(val[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FMT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_VAL; j++)
        {
            printf("%8s: [", fmt[i]);
            printf(fmt[i], val[j]);
            puts("]");
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    test_ul();
    test_sl();
    return 0;
}
```

Output (GCC 7.1.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5):

```
   %08lu: [00002413]
   %08lu: [234512349]
  %8.8lu: [00002413]
  %8.8lu: [234512349]
   %.8lu: [00002413]
   %.8lu: [234512349]
  %8.6lu: [  002413]
  %8.6lu: [234512349]
  %6.8lu: [00002413]
  %6.8lu: [234512349]
   %08ld: [00002413]
   %08ld: [-0002413]
   %08ld: [234512349]
   %08ld: [-234512349]
  %8.8ld: [00002413]
  %8.8ld: [-00002413]
  %8.8ld: [234512349]
  %8.8ld: [-234512349]
   %.8ld: [00002413]
   %.8ld: [-00002413]
   %.8ld: [234512349]
   %.8ld: [-234512349]
  %8.6ld: [  002413]
  %8.6ld: [ -002413]
  %8.6ld: [234512349]
  %8.6ld: [-234512349]
  %6.8ld: [00002413]
  %6.8ld: [-00002413]
  %6.8ld: [234512349]
  %6.8ld: [-234512349]
```

Answer (score 5):

These two are equivalent when used with an `unsigned long` (/integers), as you read in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

```
printf("V1: %08lu \n", val);
```

`0` flag will left-pads the number with zeroes (0) instead of spaces when padding is specified (see width sub-specifier).

`8` will be the `number`, in "Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger."

---

Now this:

```
printf("V2: %8.8lu \n", val);
```

will keep the effects of `8` as `number`, but will add `.8`, as `.number` in "For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X): precision specifies the minimum number of digits to be written. If the value to be written is shorter than this number, the result is padded with leading zeros. The value is not truncated even if the result is longer. A precision of 0 means that no character is written for the value 0.".

---

PS: Standard C++ should issue a diagnostic error as such:

```
prog.cc:3:11: error: '::main' must return 'int'
 void main()
           ^
```

however, even [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main) himself says that this "is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C".

Comment: This code can definitely compile C and arguably as C++ as well. In C the standard gives explicit permission for `main` to be defined "[...]in some other implementation-defined manner" (§5.1.2.2.1/1). In C++, the compiler is required to "issue at least one diagnostic message" (§[intro.compliance/2]), but having done so, is free to continue to compile the program.  "[...]this International Standard states only requirements on C++ implementations, those requirements
are often easier to understand if they are phrased as requirements on programs, parts of programs, or execution of programs."(ibid)

Comment: In addition, the code could in theory be for a freestanding systems, where all forms of main() are allowed (though the presence of VS gives away that this is a hosted Windows system).

Comment: @JerryCoffin didn't know that, updated my answer! =)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't make any difference between `%08` and `%8.8` unless you get into decimal numbers, then there is a difference. It all depends on how the user likes it. It is just a preference.